# Pentaho Dynamic SQL queries

Tags: sql, pentaho-cde

I have a Pentaho CDE project in development and i wanted to display a chart wich depends on several parameters (like month, year, precise date, country, etc). But when i want to "add" another parameter to my query, it doesn't work anymore... So i'm sure i'm doing something wrong but what ? Please take a look for the parameter month for example :

- Select_months_query : (this is for my checkbox)

`SELECT
"All" AS MONTH(TransactionDate)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(TransactionDate) FROM order ORDER BY MONTH(TransactionDate);`

- Select_barchart_query : (this is for my chart, don't mind the other tables)

`SELECT pginit.Family, SUM(order.AmountEUR) AS SALES
FROM pginit INNER JOIN statg ON pginit.PG = statg.PGInit INNER JOIN order ON statg.StatGroup = order.StatGroup
WHERE (MONTH(order.TransactionDate) IN (${month}) OR "All" IN (${month}) OR ${month} IS NULL) AND
/*/* Apply the same pattern for another parameter (like year for example) *\*\
GROUP BY pginit.Family
ORDER BY SALES;`

(Here, ${month} is a parameter in CDE)

Any ideas on how to do it ?
I read something there that said to use CASE clauses... But how ?
http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?136969-Parametrized-SQL-clause-in-CDE&highlight=dynamic

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simplifying that query until it runs and returns something and work from there.

Here are some things I would look into as possible causes:

1. I think you need single quotes around `${parameter}` expressions if they're strings;
2. `"All"` should probably be `'All'` (single quotes instead of double quotes);
3. Avoid multi-line comments. I don't think you can have multi-line comments in CDE SQL queries, although -- for single line comments usually works.
4. Be careful with multi-valued parameters; they are passed as arrays, which CDA will convert into comma separated lists. Try with a single valued parameter, using = instead of IN.

Comment: I simplified it first before posting here. I also saw that comments (even non multi lines ones) didn't work there. But i didn't know about the double/simple quotes : i thought it would be the same in SQL. And about the multi parameters, i saw too that it becomes a list separated by commas (which is a bit annoying without using string functions in javascript)

Thank you for your answers. I'll agrement that comment with a link of the pentaho forums where someone lead me on some good ideas, maybe it'll help future users here :

[link](forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?189483-Dynamic-SQL-query)